# C# UWP can't display usercontrol with code

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, user-controls

I made an Usercontrol with C# UWP, so if i create my Usercontrol with Xaml in my MainPage.Xaml I can see it.
But if I create it in my MainPage.xaml.cs with C# code i can't see it. I think i forgot something in MainPage.xaml.cs when I create my control.

I would be happy if someone have a solution for my problem :D

MyControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CustomControlTest.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomControlTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="32.06" Width="53.254">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Hello" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyControl.xaml.cs:

```
namespace CustomControlTest
{
    public sealed partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CustomControlTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomControlTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <!--<local:MyControl/>-->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace CustomControlTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            MyControl mc = new MyControl();
            mc.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            mc.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I made an Usercontrol with C# UWP, so if i create my Usercontrol with Xaml in my MainPage.Xaml I can see it. But if I create it in my MainPage.xaml.cs with C# code i can't see it

The issue is in your `MainPage.cs` constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();

   MyControl mc = new MyControl();
   mc.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
   mc.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
}
```

You create a new instance of `MyControl`, but you never add this instance to your `MainPage` instance. After constructing the instance and setting what you need to, you need to add this control to another container.

First, give your `Grid` element a name in `MainPage.xaml`:

```
 <Page
    x:Class="CustomControlTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomControlTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Name="myGrid">
        <!--<local:MyControl/>-->
    </Grid>
 </Page>
```

Next you can reference this `Grid` in your code behind and add your new `MyControl` instance to this `Grid`:

```
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();

   MyControl mc = new MyControl();
   mc.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
   mc.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

   // Add new instance of MyControl (mc) to grid control
   myGrid.Children.Add(mc);
}
```